# How I get OR to SUM(IF()) MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

i have a problem. I need to find out, how to put OR in this order:

```
SELECT ROUND(o.`total_products`  / c.`conversion_rate` - 
           (SUM(IF(pa.wholesale_price = "0" , p.wholesale_price, 
           pa.wholesale_price)*od.product_quantity)))
```

And I need to put OR together with "0" like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(o.`total_products`  / c.`conversion_rate` - 
           (SUM(IF(pa.wholesale_price = "0" OR "IS NULL", p.wholesale_price, 
           pa.wholesale_price)*od.product_quantity)))
```

I want this result: If pa.wholesale_price is zero or row does not exist, use p.wholesale_price. If pa.wholesale_price exist, use pa.wholesale_price.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: COALESCE(pa.wholesale_price,0)=0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

> IF((pa.wholesale_price = "0") OR  (pa.wholesale_price IS NULL)......

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(pa.wholesale_price = 0 OR pa.wholesale_price IS NULL, 
          p.wholesale_price, pa.wholesale_price)
```

or shorter:

```
IF(coalesce(pa.wholesale_price,0) = 0, p.wholesale_price, pa.wholesale_price)
```