# How to SUM Total of paid bills and SUM Total of no paid bills in MYSQL by month

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

When i select the values of one table

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(created,'%Y-%m')
    ,DATE_FORMAT(payday,'%Y-%m')
    ,SUM(IF(paid = 'S',total,0)) as total_paid_on_this_month
    ,SUM(IF(paid = 'N',total,0)) as total_debt_on_this_month_plus_anterior_months
FROM bills
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created,'%Y-%m')
```

Of Table bills

```
+ ---------- + ---- + ---------- + ------ + ----- +
| created    | paid | data_paid  | by     | total |
+ ---------- + ---- + ---------- + ------ + ----- +
| 2016-05-03 | Y    | 2016-08-03 | amy    | 10,00 |
| 2016-06-10 | Y    | 2016-07-03 | jorge  | 20,00 |
| 2016-05-20 | N    | 0000-00-00 |        |  5,00 |
| 2016-07-05 | N    | 0000-00-00 |        |  0,00 |
+ ---------- + ---- + ---------- + ------ + ----- +
```

What i need is the SUM of BILL per Month(that sum anterior months) and total paid(only the month that it was paid)

example:

```
one bill(10,00) was created at month 1 and paid at month 4
```

so

```
another bill(20,00) was created at month 2 and not paid yet
```

what i need

```
month 1      2      3      4
paid  00,00  00,00  00,00  10,00
bill  10,00  30,00  30,00  20,00
```

what i got

```
month 1      2      3      4
paid  00,00  00,00  00,00  10,00
bill  10,00  20,00  00,00  20,00
```

i tried

```
SELECT
    created as Start
    ,total
    ,DATE_FORMAT(IF(paid = 'S',data_paid,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),'%Y-%m') as End

FROM 'Bills'
```

and sum it on PHP in foreach

Someone can help what i could do to got it?

What i viewed:

[SQL: SUM the MAX values of results returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657881/sql-sum-the-max-values-of-results-returned?rq=1)

[How I get OR to SUM(IF()) MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501170/how-i-get-or-to-sumif-mysql?rq=1)

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/sum.php

Comment: I don't understand your data so well at all or your 10 10 10 thing. Regardless, you did a nice job with the question. +1

Comment: Under *what i got*, how did you get that output? Where's the query for that one?

Comment: see, the question changed. But the bar is set so low that even messed up data is good enough for me these days.

Comment: Not really possible. You're grouping on `created`. so if (say) you have two bills, both created Jan 1st, but one's paid on Feb1st and the other's paid March 1st, you LOSE that feb/mar data because of the grouping. You'd need two separate queries, one to calculate creation, and one to calculate payment.

Comment: That and your query result layout is a pivot table, which mysql doesn't support. The workarounds get extremely ugly, extremely fast, and can't handle arbitrary NxM row/column transforms.

Comment: With that 5 in there, I still don't follow the tables. Regardless, as I design financial systems, it is done with accounting practices and inception-to-date, and separate tables for bills and paid (or a single table like a ledger). It would not be done in this table design.